# What is the use of xref in dita?

Tags: dita, dita-ot

I have been working on dita for some time now but I am facing a problem.

What is the use of XREF in dita ? How can I use the XREF in the dita file ?

Thanks

Comment: Google is your friend here, but in short: xref (cross reference) is an element in DITA. It is used when you want to make link to the another DITA topic, different location in same content or for example to the external resource such as web site. Take a look to this link: https://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/dita/v1.3/os/part1-base/langRef/base/xref.html

Comment: Hi Barbwire, You mean to say xref is similar to anchor tag in html. Thanx